# Sending data from cakephp automatically using date and time

Tags: web-services, cakephp

I created a web services using cakephp that store on mysql some data including date and time provided by an android app.

now I want send data to another device on that **precise** date and time (kind of cron job ) but I didn't find how to do that !

any ideas how to solve that?!

Comment: You can setup a cronjob per minute and then check if current time and that precise time is equal

Comment: can I run a function from a controller in cakephp using cronjob ?

Comment: Yes for sure, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using a cronjob per minute

Command for the cronjob

`* * * * * wget -q --spider http://example.com/controller/function`

In the controller function check that precise date and time against the current date time, and they match, perform your action

```
$current_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$precise_time = "2017-05-12 9:52:00"; // for example

if($current_time == $precise_time){
    // Send data to another device
}
```